# Customizing facebook fan box css

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like, facebook-likebox

HTML, with CSS set to a file on localhost:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:like-box href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/abc/143772917800992?created" width="200" height="550" show_faces="true" stream="false" header="false" css="http://localhost/abc/templates/index/images/fb.css?1" >
</fb:like-box>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
.fan_box a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fan_box .full_widget{
  height: 200px;
  border: 0 !important;
  background: none !important;
  position: relative;
}
.fan_box .connect_top{
  background: none !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.fan_box .profileimage, .fan_box .name_block{
  display: none;
}
.fan_box .connect_action{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.fan_box .connections{
  padding: 0 !important;
  border: 0 !important;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #666;
}
span.total{
  color: #FF6600;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.fan_box .connections .connections_grid {
  padding-top: 10px !important;
}
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item{
  padding: 0 10px 10px 0 !important;
}
.fan_box .connections_grid .grid_item .name{
  font-family: "lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: #666 !important;
  padding-top: 1px !important;
}
.fan_box .connect_widget{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 10px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.fan_box .connect_widget .connect_widget_interactive_area {
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.fan_box .connect_widget td.connect_widget_vertical_center {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Facebook doesn't seem to be loading the CSS file. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

CSS can't be loaded from localhost because Facebook needs to load (and cache) it from their servers. That is, it needs to be somewhere that's accessible to their servers.

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has withdrawn this option. Now you can not add any such css file to your like box or fan box. It has been stopped working everywhere since 24th Jan 2013.

Comment: This appears to be working again! Not sure why or for how long. I couldn't find any official Facebook post for them pulling support so maybe it was in error that has now been corrected

Answer (score 0):

because the fan box is an iframe, and iframes cant be styled from the parant document.
asfaik facebook dont want to let you customize this the design to stay ci conform, however you can have the inverted color version and some other fonts.

Comment: The "css" attribute is actually valid in this case, so Facebook do let you load your own CSS. It's just not very well documented.

Comment: what do you mean with css attr?

Comment: Just that. E.g. `<fb:like-box css="http://domain.com/css_file.css">` or, for a validating example, `<div class="fb-fan" data-css="http://domain.com/css_file.css"></div>`